# Have no MIDI monitoring while playing MIDI Controller or OnScreen Keyboard - Cubase 10.5 Artist

Tags: cubase

**Have no MIDI monitoring while playing MIDI Controller or OnScreen Keyboard**

- Tracks set: input: "All MIDI In" - output: VST Rack
- MIDI is checked as "MIDI thru"
- VST Rack - channel 1 - same as track
- Tried with both instrument and rack
- MIDI Controller registers in side meters upon hitting a note
- MIDI filter all are unchcked in MIDI thru
- Recording and playback works - no MIDI monitor

Cubase 10.5 Artist - previously Cubase 7.5(LE) where everything worked properly

Answer (score 1):

If all the inputs are set up correctly, I guess we need to look at the outputs.

Is the 'audio' channel for the VST instrument assigned to the Stereo Out bus?   Is the Stereo Out bus assigned to a physical audio output on your system?

Comment: Yes all set to my Line 6 Helix, input output are working correctly over audio tracks and midi tracks. The problem is when I try to write the MIDI notes or play them the VST Rack/Instrument do not play, but when I activate the session play they do.